# Install PIL/Pillow via pip in Debian testing (Jessie)

Tags: debian, python, pip

On Debian testing (Jessie), when I try to install PIL or Pillow (python imaging libs) in a `virtualenv` via `pip` I get the following error:

```
running egg_info
writing Pillow.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to Pillow.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to Pillow.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

reading manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'Pillow.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
building 'PIL._imaging' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/libImaging
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -IlibImaging -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imaging.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imaging.o
_imaging.c:76:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have installed all dependencies for Pillow, based on my experience with Wheezy, but it seems something is different with testing.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

In fact I discovered another problem with libc6. The version I had was from experimental. After downgrading it to testing's version,  I reinstalled all dependencies but now I get a different error:

```
building 'PIL._imagingft' extension
x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/freetype2 -IlibImaging -I/usr/include/tcl8.5 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu -c _imagingft.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/_imagingft.o
_imagingft.c:62:31: fatal error: freetype/fterrors.h: No such file or directory
 #include <freetype/fterrors.h>
                               ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

It seems the experimental version of `libc6` messed things up, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Aptitude doesn't show any unmet dependencies and `aptitude install -f` does nothing.

Also, if indeed the linux-headers are relevant, the ones I have installed are:

- `linux-headers-3.11-2-all`
- `linux-headers-3.11-2-all-amd64`
- `linux-headers-3.11-2-amd64`
- `linux-headers-3.11-2-common`
- `linux-headers-3.2.0-4-amd64`
- `linux-headers-3.2.0-4-common`
- `linux-headers-amd64`

Comment: Did you installed the kernel headers (the error seems that it's related, somehow).

Comment: Linux headers are irrelevant, it's python headers that are missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After installing the development version of Pillow, the second problem was solved as well. It may be related to this [issue](https://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow/issues/425).

So to sum up, the solution was:

1. Install dependencies as Dennis said, which in my case also included downgrading the `experimental` version of libc6 with `aptitude remove libc6`, which granted the option to `DOWNGRADE` it to the repo's version.
2. Installing the Pillow's trunk version with `pip install git+git://github.com/python-imaging/Pillow.git`

Answer (score 28):

In Ubuntu 14.04 try:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/freetype2 /usr/local/include/freetype
```

Answer (score 23):

You need the python development headers, and possibly other development packages. Easiest way to get them is:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

Comment: Already tried that. In fact I can normally install `python-imaging` system-wide with `aptitude`, though I did not try to actually use it.

Comment: interesting. What's the output of that command?

Comment: this worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Debian 7 testing, and for me it worked doing this:

1. Installing the dependencies as said by Dennis:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
   ```
2. Making a symbolic link as suggested by mrudult:

   ```
   $ sudo ln -s -T /usr/include/freetype2/ /usr/include/freetype
   ```
3. Install Pillow as usual:

   ```
   $ pip install Pillow
   ```

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 install on DigitalOcean, I was able to solve this problem by simply running

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

and then re-running the pip install command inside the python venv

```
pip install Pillow
```